# Not able to pass string to formGroup

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

1.I want to loop through an array

```
*ngFor="let item of myformNameArray"
```

Think myformNameArray.length have 3 items
If I console **item** it will be like

```
myFormName1
myFormName2
myFormName3
```

I have already made these form group in my typescript component.

Example

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormName3">
```

It will work perfectly!!

But i want to loop :means

```
<div *ngFor="let item of  myformNameArray">
<form [formGroup]="{{item}}">
</form>
</div>
```

So when I do,

```
[formGroup]="{{item}}"
```

It throws me an error can't assign to object or interpolation

Or

```
[formGroup]="see(item)"
```

Where ,

```
see(item) :string {
return String(item);
}
```

**ERROR TypeError: can't assign to property "validator" on "see(item)": not an object**

Comment: how about put your form in a component, pass the item string to the component to render the form,and use component in your ngFor code?

Answer (score 1):

[formGroup] requires a FormGroup Object not string

you need to make array of formgroups instead of string names

TS:

```
myformArray = [
   this.myFormOne,
   this.myFormTwo,
   this.myFormThree
]
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of  myformArray">
    <form [formGroup]="item">
    </form>
</div>
```

you can also use formArray instead of normal array

TS:

```
myFormArray = new FormArray([]);

this.myFormArray.push(myFormOne);
this.myFormArray.push(myFormTwo);
this.myFormArray.push(myFormThree);
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let form of myFormArray.controls;">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="controlOne" />
    <input formControlName="ControlTwo" />
  </form>
</div>
```

And also you should not use both square brackets and curly brackets (interpolation) for property binding, use either square brackets or interpolation.

internally angular converts square brackets to interpolation

either do this : `[formGroup]="item"`
or this : `formGroup="{{item}}"`

not both